# How to get portion of ini file by section using sed in bash

Tags: regex, awk, sed

How to get a portion of ini file by section name using sed. 
The tricky part is the section name might have file paths.

Example of my ini:

```
[SECTION]
ANYkey=value1
ANYkey2=value2

[test/foo/file.txt]
key=value1
key2=value2

[test/foo/file2.txt]
key3=value3
key4=value4
```

Issue is in retrieving data of ini section [test/foo/file.txt]

expected output after sed or awk:

```
key=value1
key2=value2
```

I have coded below to get [SECTION] portion using below

```
sed -e 's/[[:space:]]*\=[[:space:]]*/=/g' -e 's/#.*$//' -e 's/[[:space:]]*$//' -e 's/^[[:space:]]*//' -e "s/^\(.*\)=\([^\"']*\)$/\1=\"\2\"/" < file.ini | sed -n -e "/^\[SECTION\]/,/^\s*\[/{/^[^#].*\=.*/p;}"
```

Got the output using sed like

```
ANYkey=value1
ANYkey2=value2
```

But this logic is not working for other section due to file path (slashes in between [test/foo/file.txt])

Comment: Could you please be more clear in your question as its not clear whats the logic of getting output(do you want to remove paths line?). Also please do add your efforts which you have put in order to solve your own problem in your question and let us know then.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13: Sure. Here is the example to give more clarification.
my file.ini looks like below
```
[SECTION]
anykey=anyvalue
anykey2=anyvalue2

[test/foo/file.txt]
key=value1
key2=value2
```

Comment: I can able to get portion of SECTION using below sed but unable to retrieve other section ([test/foo/file.txt])

```
sed -e 's/[[:space:]]*\=[[:space:]]*/=/g' -e 's/#.*$//' -e 's/[[:space:]]*$//' -e 's/^[[:space:]]*//' -e "s/^\(.*\)=\([^\"']*\)$/\1=\"\2\"/" < file.ini | sed -n -e "/^\[SECTION\]/,/^\s*\[/{/^[^#].*\=.*/p;}"

``` 
the output of above sed gives me
```
anykey=anyvalue
anykey2=anyvalue2

Comment: Good, thanks for showing efforts, please add them in your question(as comments are not meant to show code) with CODE TAGS and let us know then.

Comment: Please recheck my post now

Comment: Many thanks for doing so. One clarification, so you want those lines which start with `key`? Or you want lines comes after your path line, could you please do let us know on same.

Comment: I just need to get lines after my path into file or something like >output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***EDIT2:*** OR as per OP's comment in case you want to get value as an argument passed to a script then try following. Should be used when OP needs to pass path details as an argument to a shell script and pass it to `awk` program to get desired output.

```
cat script.ksh
value="$1"
awk -v var="$value" '/^\[/{found=""} $0 ~ var{found=1;next}  found && NF' Input_file
```

Run script as follows and output will be:

```
./script.ksh "test/foo/file.txt"
key=value1
key2=value2
```

---

---

***EDIT:*** Based on OP's comment to look for specific pat try following. Should be used when OP wants to directly pass path details in `awk` program itself.

```
awk '/^\[/{found=""} /^\[test\/foo\/file\.txt\]$/{found=1;next} found && NF' Input_file
```

OR

```
awk '/^\[/{found=""} $0 == "[test/foo/file2.txt]"{found=1;next} found && NF' Input_file
```

***Explanation for above:***

```
awk '                              ##Starting awk program from here.
/^\[/{                             ##Checking if a line starts from [.
  found=""                         ##Nullifying found here.
}
/^\[test\/foo\/file\.txt\]$/{       ##Checking if a line contains [test/foo.... then do following.
  found=1                          ##Setting found here.
  next                             ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
found && NF                        ##Checking if found is SET and line is NOT empty then print current line.
' Input_file                       ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

---

---

Based on your shown samples, could you please try following. Should be used when any section after `[` needs to be printed.

```
awk '/^\[/{found=""} /^\[.*\//{found=1;next} found' Input_file
```

***Explanation for above:***

```
awk '           ##Starting awk program from here.
/^\[/{          ##Checking if a line starts with [ then do following.
  found=""      ##Nullifying found here.
}
/^\[.*\//{      ##Checking condition if line starts from [ and have / in it for path then do following.
  found=1       ##Setting found to 1 here.
  next          ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
found           ##If found is set then print current line.
' Input_file    ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: Sure, let me try

Comment: This will not resolve if my ini has more than one section with file paths.
[test/foo/file.txt]
key=value
[test/foo/file2.txt
key=value2
[test/foo/file3.txt]
key=value3

Comment: @user1125741, so you want only 1 path i output? Could you please clarify on it.

Comment: Recheck my post (edited)....which might give you sample of my ini how it looks like.
your code will help me if my ini file has any path. but there could be multiple sections with paths.
So I need to get only portion under that path before next path.

Comment: which means, section name [test/foo/file.txt] should go as an argument in awk or sed to get proper lines in output

Comment: @user1125741, please try my EDIT2 and EDIT solutions and lemme know how it goes?

Comment: Sure. Let me try...Thanks a lot Champ!!

Comment: @user1125741, Added 3 of the solutions with their use cases too, lemme know how it goes?

Comment: With `/^\[test\/foo\/file.txt\]$/` you're trying to escape all the regexp metachars (you missed on `.` -> `\.`) and delimiters to make that regexp comparison behave like a string comparison. Don't do that - just do a string comparison `$0 == "[test/foo/file2.txt]"` as that's simpler, more robust and less error-prone.

Comment: @EdMorton, Thank you sir for letting know, added that in OR solution + fixed escaping `.` in code, cheers.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk -v sec='[test/foo/file2.txt]' '!NF{f=0} f; $0==sec{f=1}' file
key3=value3
key4=value4
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution selects a value in .ini section using only sed and bash.

```bash
#!/bin/bash
set -eu

function sed_escape {
    sed -r 's%([/.])%\\\1%g' <<< "$*"
}

SECTION=$(sed_escape "$1")
KEY=$(sed_escape "$2")

sed -rn -e "/^\[${SECTION}\]$/,/^\[.*/ { /^${KEY}=/ s/.*=//p }"
```

For simplicity, I took some hypothesis :

- no extra white spaces in INI file
- ne fancy character in section name or key name, except / and .
- no comment in INI file

```bash
jpoittevin@poittevin:~
$./find_ini.sh SECTION ANYkey2 < test.ini 
value2
```